# Node js csv-writer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv

Using the CreateCsvWriter to convert an array of objects into a csv, however; an error is returned: TypeError: record.map is not a function. This fnction works well when i define an object of headers but what i need is a csv with no headers, just rows of data.

```
const createCsvWriter = require("csv-writer").createArrayCsvWriter;

const csv_creater = (data) => {
  const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: "exports.csv",
    header: false
  });

  csvWriter
    .writeRecords(data)
    .then(() => console.log("exports csv created successfully!"));

  return csvWriter;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to docs - if you don't want to write a header line, don't give title to header elements and just give field IDs as a string:

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
    path: 'path/to/file.csv',
    header: ['name', 'lang']
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function works if you pass an array of records. e.g.

```js
const records = [['a', 'b', 'c']]
csv_creater(records)
```

From the error message, I'm guessing you're passing just one record (`['a', 'b', 'c']` in this example) instead of an array of records.